# Nginx uwsgi_pass not working with location set to anything besides /

Tags: docker, nginx, flask, uwsgi

Just getting started with Docker, Nginx, and uWSGI. I've got a flask app that works great when I define a location like this:

```
    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass flask:8080;
    }
```

... but I'd like to have multiple applications (some running Flask, some Django, some Node, etc) running at different locations, so I can do stuff like:

- https://myhost.com/app1 - Flask
- https://myhost.com/app2 - Django
- https://myhost.com/app3 - Node

I was hoping to just do this:

```
    location /app1/ {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass flask:8080;
    }
```

... but I get a 404 back from Flask & Nginx:

```
nginx    | xxx.xxx.xxx.x - - [18/Dec/2019:23:18:09 +0000] "GET /app3/ HTTP/2.0" 404 232 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1.1 Safari/605.1.15" "-"
flask    | [pid: 6|app: 0|req: 1/1] xxx.xxx.xxx.x () {38 vars in 602 bytes} [Wed Dec 18 23:18:09 2019] GET /app3/ => generated 232 bytes in 2 msecs (HTTP/2.0 404) 2 headers in 72 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

Here's the success/`200` I get when I use `/` for the location:

```
flask    | [pid: 10|app: 0|req: 2/3] xxx.xxx.xxx.x () {38 vars in 592 bytes} [Wed Dec 18 23:30:33 2019] GET / => generated 65 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/2.0 200) 2 headers in 79 bytes (1 switches on core 1)
nginx    | xxx.xxx.xxx.x - - [18/Dec/2019:23:30:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 200 65 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1.1 Safari/605.1.15" "-"
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You're sending the `/appN/` path along to the upstream service. Either strip it out in nginx before proxy, or have each service know that it needs to respond to requests rooted at `/appN/`.

Comment: Thanks, @wmorrell. I added a `/` to my Flask route (so changed it from `/app1` to `/app1/`, and it worked. Much appreciated.